# Javascript How to write localStorage script

Tags: javascript, local-storage

How to write localStorage script which will remember the value of turning odometer...so that each time the user visits the site again , the odometer will resume on the value on which odometer was at when the user left the site? I'm beginner in javascript so please understand...

This is my code: https://jsfiddle.net/aht87opr/17/

I've found the following code which might help with my case: http://jsfiddle.net/Jonathan_Ironman/Hn7jc/

```
$('button').click(function() {
    var mefedron = myOdometer.get();
    $('#value').text(mefedron);
});
```

Comment: Did you try the example from [MDN localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/LocalStorage)?

Comment: You really can't get much simpler, it's a very simple key / value store..  eg.. set ->  `localStorage.setItem('score', theScore)` & get -> `theScore = localStorage.getItem('score')|0`

Comment: @Keith it would be great if somebody could adress the code in relation to the jsfiddle link which I provided. I've tried all answers here but neither worked on jsfiddle. I'm wondering what am I doing wrong. I stated that I am a beginner

Answer (score 1):

Nicely done on the odometer, looks good.  Local storage is simple.
To set local storage:

```
localStorage.setItem("key", "value");
```

To get local storage:

```
var number = localStorage.getItem("key");
```

Be sure to try getting the local storage first so you can handle any null errors.

Comment: +1, but you should maybe mention that you should wrap `localStorage ` usage in an `try, catch` block or check if it's available first, because it could be unavailable due to old browser or `private surfing` mode on mobile devices.

Comment: @RyanWalker it would be great if somebody could adress the code in relation to the jsfiddle link which I provided. I've tried all answers here but neither worked on jsfiddle. I'm wondering what am I doing wrong. I stated that I am a beginner

Comment: I'm not familiar with jsfiddle, but that might be the problem.  Try this on a normal .html document in your browser

Answer (score 0):

## Get and Set

`localStorage` has a few ways to get and set values to the browser. The simplest is treating it like a regular object.

```
localStorage.distance = 55;
```

you can then retrieve the value by accessing the property name you created earlier.

```
console.log(localStorage.distance); // "55"
```

## Strings are stored, parse the string

Notice that `localStorage.distance` was set as a number but when accessed was a string. If you only need to store a number you could pass the string through a function like `parseInt()`.

```
console.log(parseInt(localStorage.distance)); // 55
```

## Another solution is to use JSON

create an object model of your odometer.

```
var odometer = { distance: 55, timeForOilChange: false };
```

Then write to the `localStorage` passing your model through `JSON.stringify`

```
localStorage.odometer = JSON.stringify(odometer);
```

and read the value back out using `JSON.parse`

```
console.log(JSON.parse(localStorage.odometer)); 
// { distance: 55, timeForOilChange: false }
```

Comment: t3dodson thank you...but I don't know how to actually implement that information to my code , would you be kind enough to help please ? https://jsfiddle.net/aht87opr/26/

Comment: @Habanera Sorry, Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. Please ask another more directed answer for clarity. Stack Overflow will not give the complete code solution to you but will answer any conceptual problem you face.

Comment: @Habanera Here is a link to tutorials that cover basic concepts. http://referencedesigner.com/tutorials/js/js_1.php

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/nech0L9e/4/ (this is my attempt to write localstorage script myself) .The problem with it is that I wanted 
after page refresh to go back to exact number where it was when I was leaving the page now...my local storage script, as one can see, does not do that namely there might be problems on lines 125 where I tried to create loadOrCreate function and on line 129 and 144, there has to be something wrong...@t3dodson